# CentOS 7 grub configuration for Hyper-V

Tags: centos, grub2, vmware, hyper-v

I converted a CentOS 7 vm from VMWare Workstation 12.5 to Hyper-V. Both hypervisors are running on top of Windows 10.

Upon boot I get dropped into a rescue shell because the kernel can not find the root partition.  If I use the second grub menu option (the rescue) option, the new vm will boot OK.

This is the contents of my `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg`:
[image: grub.cfg]

This is my `/etc/fstab`:
[image: fstab]

When I am in rescue mode, these are the actual partition mappings:
[image: mappings]

What file(s) and commands to I need to edit/run in order to get the system to boot normally again?

Comment: /boot/grub/grub.cfg

Comment: There is not /boot/grub/grub.cfg.  grub.cfg lives under /boot/grub2

Comment: The UUIDs surely have changed, no? I would relabel the partitions, and do a grub-install

Comment: @Rui: what commands to relabel?

Comment: ` xfs_admin -L media /dev/sdb1` see https://ubuntuswitch.wordpress.com/2007/06/04/howto-rename-a-xfs-filesystem-label-it/

Comment: @Rui: I just verified that the UUIDs did not change during the conversion with `xfs_admin -u /dev/sda3`  (and with /dev/sda1)

Comment: Then do a grub-install /dev/sda (not this exact syntax), reboot and cross your fingers.